# Spring Bean wrong path

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am getting this error and I can't figure out why. I believe its the path. Tried to change it several times but no success.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field loginDelegate in com.codeEvaluator.controller.LoginController required a bean of type 'com.codeEvaluator.delegate.LoginDelegate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.codeEvaluator.delegate.LoginDelegate' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my sprinBeanConfiguration.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">



<bean id="loginDelegate" class="com.codeEvaluator.delegate.LoginDelegate">
    <property name="userService" ref="userService"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="userService" class="com.codeEvaluator.service.impl.UserServiceImpl">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"></property>
</bean>

<bean name="userDao" class="com.codeEvaluator.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/codeevaluator" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

My springWeb.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.jcg" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
```

```
<import resource="springBeanConfiguration.xml"/>
```

Controller class

```
package com.codeEvaluator.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.codeEvaluator.delegate.LoginDelegate;
import com.codeEvaluator.viewBean.LoginBean;


@Controller
public class LoginController
{
        @Autowired
    private LoginDelegate loginDelegate;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, LoginBean loginBean)
    {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
        //LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean();
        model.addObject("loginBean", loginBean);
        return model;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView executeLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("loginBean")LoginBean loginBean)
    {
            ModelAndView model= null;
            try
            {
                    boolean isValidUser = loginDelegate.isValidUser(loginBean.getUsername(), loginBean.getPassword());
                    if(isValidUser)
                    {
                            System.out.println("User Login Successful");
                            request.setAttribute("loggedInUser", loginBean.getUsername());
                            model = new ModelAndView("welcome");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            model = new ModelAndView("login");
                            request.setAttribute("message", "Invalid credentials!!");
                    }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return model;
    }
}
```

This is a project view.

[image]

The login.jsp is inside de jsp package.

Comment: Share your web.xml so that we can check the application contexts configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jcg, com.codeEvaluator" />
```

and your import should be something like this

```
<import resource="classpath:springBeanConfiguration.xml"/>
```

or

```
<import resource="classpath*:springBeanConfiguration.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "sprinBeanConfiguration.xml" file add those annotations  `<context:component-scan base-package="com.codeEvaluator" />` and`<context:annotation-config>` to enable annotation "@Autowired"